# memory location and data race in c

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, gcc

http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#memory-model

the page describe that :

```
// thread 1:
char c;
c = 1;
int x = c;

// thread 2:
char b;
b = 1;
int y = b;
```

.....

**However, most modern processors cannot read or write a single character, it must read or write a whole word, so the assignment to c really is ``read the word containing c, replace the c part, and write the word back again.'' Since the assignment to b is similar, there are plenty of opportunities for the two threads to clobber each other even though the threads do not (according to their source text) share data!**

I have a struct :

```
struct data_
{
    volatile char c ;
    volatile char b ;
}  __attribute__(( aligned(2) ));
typedef struct data_ data ;
```

and global vars:

```
data dx ; 
int x,y ;
```

Thread1 :

```
    dx.c = 1 ;
    x = dx.c ;
```

Thread2 :

```
    dx.b = 1 ;
    y = dx.b ;
```

Compiled at gcc 4.4.6 ,  and run it 1,000,000 times ,
 look like I don't get any value that not (x==1 && y==1) !!!!

```
struct data_
{
    volatile char c ;
    volatile char b ;
}  __attribute__(( aligned(2) ));
```

I put char c and char b in a structure aligned(2) on purpose so that they both belong to 
the same word ,  and according to the webpage describe , I might have the chance 
to get results not (x==1 && y==1) , the fact is that run the test 1,000,000 time ,
all get (x==1 && y==1)  , is that because gcc do any tricks ? or something I missed ?

Edit :

Thread1 :

```
int ilocal ;
while(1)
{
    sem_wait(sem1) ;
    dx.c = 1 ;
    x = dx.c ;
    ilocal = __sync_add_and_fetch(&icnt,1) ;
    if(ilocal == 2)
        sem_post(sem3) ;
    ++icnt1 ;
}
```

Thread2 :

```
int ilocal ;
while(1)
{
    sem_wait(sem2) ;
    dx.b = 1 ;
    y = dx.b ;
    ilocal = __sync_add_and_fetch(&icnt,1) ;
    if(ilocal == 2)
        sem_post(sem3) ;
    ++icnt2 ;
}
```

Main :

```
int idx,iflag1=0,iflag2=0 ;
for(idx=0;idx<1000000;idx++)
{
    icnt = 0 ; dx.c=0 ; dx.b=0 ;
    sem_post(sem1) ;
    sem_post(sem2) ;
    sem_wait(sem3) ;
    if( ! ((x==1)&&(y==1))  )
    {
        printf("result that (x==%d && y==%d) \n",x,y) ;
        ++iflag1 ;
    }else{
        ++iflag2 ;
    }
} //while
printf("iflag1=(%d),iflag2=(%d)\n",iflag1,iflag2) ;
printf("icnt1=(%d),icnt2=(%d) \n",icnt1,icnt2) ;
```

gcc   memorylocate.c -lpthread -o memorylocate.exe

```
sizeof data=(64) //source already change to __attribute__(( aligned(64) )
iflag1=(0),iflag2=(1000000)
icnt1=(1000000),icnt2=(1000000)
```

Edit2 :

I think I finally figure it out !!

```
struct { char c ; char b ;}
```

c and b would be different memory location , so that they can be thread-safe access !!
the cpu can access single-byte char atomiclly !!!!!

I change code to :

```
struct data_
{
    unsigned char c:4 ;
    unsigned char b:4 ;
} ;
```

and in main :

```
for(idx=0;idx<1000000;idx++)
{
    icnt = 0 ; dx.c=0 ; dx.b=0 ;
    sem_post(sem1) ;
    sem_post(sem2) ;
    sem_wait(sem3) ;
    if( ! ((dx.c==1)&&(dx.b==1))  )
    {
        printf("result that (x==%d && y==%d) \n",x,y) ;
        ++iflag1 ;
    }else{
        ++iflag2 ;
    }
} //while
```

I observe there are results that not (dx.c==1)&&(dx.b==1)  !! This is because the dx.c and dx.b is in the same memory location in this case !!!!

So I make a mistake , the most important thing to decide is memory location , struct {char c; char b;}  , char c and char b is in different memory location , the  test result is correct !!!!

Comment: It's not just whether they are in the same word, align to your cache size to make sure that they are actually in the same cache line too.

Comment: @kfsone,thanks,change to aligned(64) , still get the same results,  you mean this is just only a false sharing issue ?

Comment: Do you have code that changes `dx.b` or `dx.c` to some value other than 1?

Comment: @greatwolf , yes , in the main thread set dx.b and dx.c both to 0 , and semaphore post thread1 and thread2 to run ,and get the result from main thread , all the time get (x==1 && y==1)

Comment: @greatwolf , I have posted the main and thread1,thread2 codes ..

Comment: Most likely the two threads are being serialized due to the `sem_wait`. The first `sem_post` wakes the first thread, and then by the time the second `sem_post` has been executed and the second thread scheduled, the first thread is already done writing.

Comment: What is this "modern CPU" that cannot do atomic byte writes? I know for a fact that x86 and ARM (at least armv7) don't have this problem. Old Alpha couldn't do atomic byte accesses, but they hardly qualify as modern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see 1.7 [intro.memory] p3 in the C++ Standard:

> A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal
>   sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having non-zero width. [ Note:
>   ... ] Two or more threads of execution (1.10) can update and access
>   separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

So a conforming compiler just has to ensure that a char can be updated without affecting other memory locations.

Comment: ...unless you use non-standard extensions to mess with the alignment, in which case you have to consult your compiler manual to be sure.